# Substitute for Progress Bar in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, progress-bar, updateprogress

What should I use as a substitute for **`Progress bar`** in **`ASP.Net`**?
I am planning to use **`UpdateProgress`** but I think I can not show there the percentage of the data that I am processing, or is there other way that I can show the percentage of the data that I am processing using **`UpdateProgress`**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a postback trigger and check the progress of the background operation, then update the status of a [jQuery ProgressBar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Progressbar).

Eg:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="progress"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>

    // register a startup script to update a jQuery ProgressBar. Use the page request manager as the $().ready event won't fire - the DOM has already been loaded:
    var js = @" Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(s,e) {
        $('#progress').progressbar("value" , 50);
    });
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "jsProgress", "  ", true);
```

Comment: where I should put this? "var js = @" Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(s,e) {
        $('#progress').progressbar("value" , 50);
    });"

Comment: In the code-behind. It just needs to be registered with the ScriptManager.